# Redraw datatables after using ajax to refresh the table content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using [Datatables](http://datatables.net) and have a button on the page that refreshes the table using AJAX. To be clear the table isn't using an ajax source of data, we are just using ajax to refresh it only when needed. Ajax is refreshing the div which the table is wrapped in. I know i'm losing my pagination buttons and filtering capability because the table needs to be redrawn but i'm not sure how to add this into the table initialization code.

Datatables code

```
var oTable6;
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable6 = $('#rankings').dataTable( {
        "sDom":'t<"bottom"filp><"clear">',
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [ 
            { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "10px" },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ]

    });
});
```

The ajax code is this

```
$("#ajaxchange").click(function(){
    var campaign_id = $("#campaigns_id").val();
    var fromDate = $("#from").val();
    var toDate = $("#to").val();

    var url = 'http://domain.com/account/campaign/ajaxrefreshgrid?format=html';
    $.post(url, { campaignId: campaign_id, fromdate: fromDate, todate: toDate},
        function( data ) { 
            $("#ajaxresponse").html(data);
        });
});
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
"fnDrawCallback": function() {
    function( data ) { 
        $("#ajaxresponse").html(data);
    };
},
```

Comment: Could you post your full datatables code as well as the html related to it?

Comment: I've updated the code above to show the entire initialization for the table

Comment: @agunn why don't you link to the chosen answer on that question rather than your own ? The chosen answer at that question is http://stackoverflow.com/a/7890909/804087

Comment: NB: For users of the modern datatables api (v1.10 and above), I've posted an answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40554137/165164) that uses that variation. AFAICS, all of the answers to this question so far use the v1.9 and prior api syntax.

Comment: @anagio, I linked to my answer below because I believe it is useful to have a pointer here to a newer answer that refers to the newer DT api. I did not refer to any other SO post question/answer because I had not found one that used modern DT 1.10 api syntax. I appreciate your right to question whether or not I made the correct choice but it appears to me that you actually deleted my comment. Am I confused? I don't think deleting my comment, rather than responding to it, is in the spirit of SO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks as if you could use the API functions to

- clear the table ( fnClearTable )
- add new data to the table ( fnAddData)
- redraw the table ( fnDraw )

http://datatables.net/api

**UPDATE**

I guess you're using the [DOM Data Source](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/dom.html) (for server-side processing) to generate your table. I didn't really get that at first, so my previous answer won't work for that.

To get it to work without rewriting your server side code:

What you'll need to do is totally remove the old table (in the dom) and replace it with the ajax result content, then reinitialize the datatable:

```
// in your $.post callback:

function (data) {

    // remove the old table
    $("#ajaxresponse").children().remove();

    // replace with the new table
    $("#ajaxresponse").html(data);

    // reinitialize the datatable
    $('#rankings').dataTable( {
    "sDom":'t<"bottom"filp><"clear">',
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [ 
        { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "10px" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
        ]

    } 
    );
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to work with all three of these with no luck. I can call clearTable before the ajax function i see the old data clear. I then have fnDraw after the ajax function and it's not redrawing the table. The ajax response includes other html not just the <table> so i'm sure I need to redraw the #rankings table specifically

Comment: It looks to me as if the fnAddData function takes an array of data, not HTML

Comment: Well is there anyway to refresh my table without recoding the ajax to get an array?

Answer (score 13):

Try destroying the datatable with bDestroy:true like this:

```
$("#ajaxchange").click(function(){
    var campaign_id = $("#campaigns_id").val();
    var fromDate = $("#from").val();
    var toDate = $("#to").val();

    var url = 'http://domain.com/account/campaign/ajaxrefreshgrid?format=html';
    $.post(url, { campaignId: campaign_id, fromdate: fromDate, todate: toDate},
            function( data ) { 

                $("#ajaxresponse").html(data);

                oTable6 = $('#rankings').dataTable( {"bDestroy":true,
                    "sDom":'t<"bottom"filp><"clear">',
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aoColumns": [ 
        { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "10px" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
        ]

} 
);
            });

});
```

bDestroy: true will first destroy and datatable instance associated with that selector before reinitializing a new one.

Comment: Sorry for a noob question but how did you fill the new data in the table? Is this `$("#ajaxresponse").html(data);` it?

Comment: That works for me. I get my spagetti content into table with ajax. And i add `"bDestroy":true,` into parameters. After that initialize datatable every ajax content loaded. thnx @Keith.Abramo

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why.  But

```
oTable6.fnDraw();
```

Works for me.  I put it in the next line.

Comment: because `oTable6` is initiated using `$(element).dataTables()` not `DataTables` class.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
var table = $(selector).dataTables();
table.api().draw(false);
```

or

```
var table = $(selector).DataTables();
table.draw(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

For users of modern DataTables (1.10 and above), all the answers and examples on this page are for the old api, not the new. I had a very hard time finding a newer example but finally did find [this DT forum post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/35816) (TL;DR for most folks) which led me to [this concise example](http://live.datatables.net/codewude/1/edit).

The example code worked for me after I finally noticed the $() selector syntax immediately surrounding the html string. You have to add a node not a string.

That example really is worth looking at but, in the spirit of SO, if you just want to see a snippet of code that works:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  table.rows.add( $(
          '<tr>'+
          '  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>'+
          '  <td>System Architect</td>'+
          '  <td>Edinburgh</td>'+
          '  <td>61</td>'+
          '  <td>2011/04/25</td>'+
          '  <td>$3,120</td>'+
          '</tr>'
  ) ).draw();
```

The careful reader might note that, since we are adding only one row of data, that table.row.add(...) should work as well and did for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
var dataTable = $('#HelpdeskOverview').dataTable();

var oSettings = dataTable.fnSettings();
dataTable.fnClearTable(this);
for (var i=0; i<json.aaData.length; i++)
{
   dataTable.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
}
oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
dataTable.fnDraw();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the initialization use:

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                    //* Add some extra data to the sender *
                    newData = aoData;
                    newData.push({ "name": "key", "value": $('#value').val() });

                    $.getJSON( sSource, newData, function (json) {
                        //* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables *
                        fnCallback(json);
                    } );
                },
```

And then just use:

```
$("#table_id").dataTable().fnDraw();
```

The important thing in the fnServerData is:

```
    newData = aoData;
    newData.push({ "name": "key", "value": $('#value').val() });
```

if you push directly to aoData, the change is permanent the first time you draw the table and fnDraw don't work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I feed my table with data retrieved by ajax (not sure if this is the best practice tough, but it feels intuitive and works well):

```
/* initialise table */
oTable1 = $( '.tables table' ).dataTable
( {
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
    'bLengthChange': false,
    'aaData': [],
    'aoColumns': [{"sTitle": "Tables"}],
    'bAutoWidth': true
} );


 /*retrieve data*/
function getArr( conf_csv_path )
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url  : 'my_url'
        success  : function( obj ) 
        {
            update_table( obj );
        }
    });
}


/* build table data */
function update_table( arr )
{        
    oTable1.fnClearTable();
    for ( input in arr )
    {
        oTable1.fnAddData( [ arr[input] );
    }                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check fnAddData: https://legacy.datatables.net/ref

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#example').dataTable();
  var url = '/RESTApplicationTest/webresources/entity.person';
  $.get(url, function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      table.fnAddData([data[i].idPerson, data[i].firstname, data[i].lastname, data[i].email, data[i].phone])
    }
  });
});
```