# DataTables is overflowing and change columns width

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have a DataTables loaded by ajax request.
Everytime when the table is drawed, layout's table breaks and, when change the entires, for to see more lines, it changes again the size of columns.

[You can find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKBBa.png)

What I need?

- Table with fixed width (I tried table-layout: fixed, but not works)
- Change entires and keep the same width measure when load
- DataTables, draw columns without overflow

Somebody?

Comment: are setting the width of the table? take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253963/table-with-table-layout-fixed-and-how-to-make-one-column-wider

Comment: Hi, you should read the guide to this site as you will be starting having down-votes for your question, and perhaps someone will try (correctly) to close it. Provide data and code of your work and specify what you've tried and where the bug is.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. In those questions learn how to properly provide a [mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable) example.

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819036/redraw-datatables-after-using-ajax-to-refresh-the-table-content